# Python pandas: compare data and put together

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

im using pandas to read out a csv-file and an xlsx-file. Both files have one common column with numbers. I save both datasets in two seperate lists. Now i want to check the columns with the common values and add the dataset from the second list to the first. The criteria is that the values must match. Hope you understand what i want to do.

Here are the lists:
List 1:

```
       FAK-ART    FAK-DAT  LEIST-DAT      KD-CRM MW-BW       EQ-NR MATERIAL  \
```

Now i need a hint how to solve this. I googled a lot and didnt find the solution for my problem. Would be great if someone could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html):

```
print (pd.merge(df1, df2, on='EQ-NR', how='left'))

   FAK-ART     FAK-DAT   LEIST-DAT KD-CRM MW-BW       EQ-NR MATERIAL  \
0     ZPAF  2015-05-18  2015-05-31    D     E  100714  S   
1     ZPAF  2015-05-18  2015-05-31    D     B  100473  S   
2     ZPAF  2015-05-18  2015-05-31    D     E  100608  S   
3     ZPAF  2015-05-18  2015-05-31    D     B  100704  S   
4     ZPAF  2015-05-18  2015-05-31    D     E  100823  S   
5     ZPAF  2015-05-18  2015-05-31    D     B  100985  S   
6     ZPAF  2015-05-18  2015-05-31    D     E  100774  S   
7     ZPAF  2015-05-18  2015-05-31    D     B  100790  S   
8     ZPAF  2015-05-18  2015-05-31    D     E  100082  S   
9     ZPAF  2015-05-18  2015-05-31    D     B  100097  S   
10    ZPAF  2015-05-18  2015-05-31    D     E  100563  S   
11    ZPAF  2015-05-18  2015-05-31    D     B  100566  S   
12    ZPAF  2015-05-18  2015-05-31    D     E  100569  S   
13    ZPAF  2015-05-18  2015-05-31    D     B  100180  S   
14    ZPAF  2015-05-18  2015-05-31    D     E  100748  S   
15    ZPAF  2015-05-18  2015-05-31    D     B  100752  S   
16    ZPAF  2015-05-18  2015-05-31    D     E  100753  S   

           TA  
0   SONSTIGES  
1         NaN  
2   Sonstiges  
3   Sonstiges  
4   Sonstiges  
5   Sonstiges  
6        D  
7        D  
8         H  
9         NaN  
10  Sonstiges  
11  Sonstiges  
12  SONSTIGES  
13        NaN  
14        NaN  
15        NaN  
16        NaN
```